# matplotlib: when using style 'fivethirtyeight', how to draw gridline behind bar and legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, gridlines

As title, how can I move my gridline behind when using style such as 'fivethirtyeight'?

I have tried 
`Axis.set_axisbelow(True)` and `ax.grid(zorder=0)`
, but none of them works.

[The figure is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qZUp.png)

As you can see, the gridline is on top of the legend, making it difficult to read.

The code is shown here:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')



data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Bacterial alpha-amylase', 1.0, 4.0, 0.0, 4.0] ,
['Fungal glucoamylase', 7.5, 24.0, 0.0, 24.0] ,
['Fungal phytase', 2.2, 6.0, 0.0, 6.0] ,
['Bacterial protease', 4.3, 14.0, 0.0, 14.0] ,
['Bacterial amylase', 10.2, 29.0, 0.0, 29.0] ,
['GSK_A', 12.0, 65.0, 0.0, 65.0] ,
['GSK_B', 3.0, 25.0, 0.0, 25.0] ,
['GSK_C', 4.0, 35.0, 0.0, 35.0] ,
['Ecoinvent_Europe', 6.4237, 0.052362, 0.0, 0.052362] ,
['Ecoinvent_rest of world', 8.8557, 0.056691, 0.0, 0.056691] ,
['Rhodium', 34967.0, 587.81, 587.81, 0.0]]), 
columns = ['enzyme', 'GWP100', 'Acidification', 'new_acid_2', 'new_acid_1'])

# the one below is to convert my numbers to float,
# which is set as string by default in the first place by python

for i in data.columns.values:
    if i =='enzyme':
        pass
    else:
        data[i] = data[i].astype(float)




fig = plt.figure(2, figsize=(6,4))


ax3 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax4 = ax3.twinx()

data['new_acid_2'] = data.Acidification
data.loc[data['new_acid_2']<100, 'new_acid_2'] = 0

data['new_acid_1'] = data.Acidification
data.loc[data['new_acid_1'] > 100, 'new_acid_1'] = 0


my_label = data.enzyme.values


x_pos = np.arange(11)


h1 = ax3.bar(x_pos, data.new_acid_1.values,  label=my_label)
h2 = ax4.bar(x_pos, data.new_acid_2.values,  label=my_label)
h1[-1].set_color('maroon')
h2[-1].set_color('maroon')


ax3.legend(h2,my_label, loc = 2,fontsize = 8)
ax3.set_axisbelow(True)


plt.show()
```

How can I move my gridline behind when using style such as 'fivethirtyeight'?

Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to not show the twin axis grid lines because it makes the `ax3` spacing look uneven. Add the following two lines after plotting `h1` and `h2`

```
ax3.grid(zorder=0)
ax4.grid(False)
```

Alternative solution is by using `zorder=1` while plotting bar plot. The `zorder` of bars should be greater than that of the grid (default 0). Think of the `zorder` as the depth of the two-d canvas/figure you see where the depth gone into the paper/screen.

```
h1 = ax3.bar(x_pos, data.new_acid_1.values,  label=my_label,zorder=1)
h2 = ax4.bar(x_pos, data.new_acid_2.values,  label=my_label, zorder=1)
ax3.grid(True)
ax4.grid(False)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bazingaa.

I use `ax4.grid(False)` and it is much better.

But what if I still want the gridline for twin axis (ax2), how can I achieve this?


either `ax4.grid(zorder =0)`   or 
`h2 = ax4.bar(x_pos, data.new_acid_2.values,  label=my_label,zorder=1)` does not work to make gridline of twin axis behind bar and legend.

Comment: Use ax2.grid(False)